# Nested subquery in select clause, SQL

Tags: sql

> I'm getting this "SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Sintaxe incorreta próxima a
> ')'.",

I think I've never tried this before.

```
SELECT V.NUMERO_PATRIMONIO, 
       P.NOME, 
       S.NOME, 
       V.PLACA, 
       V.MARCA, 
       V.MODELO, 
       V.ANO_FABRICACAO, 
       V.FROTA_TEXTO, 
       V.RENAVAM, 
       V.COMBUSTIVEL, 
       V.BAIXADO,
       ( select ultimo_abastecimento, qtd  
         from ( select max(fa.data_cadastro) as ultimo_abastecimento, qtd   
                from frota_abastecimento as fa where fa.veiculo  = v.id group by fa.veiculo 
              ) 
        ) s
FROM FROTA_VEICULO V
LEFT JOIN PATRIMONIO_TOMBAMENTO T ON T.PLACA = V.NUMERO_PATRIMONIO and (v.ID_ORGAO = t.id_orgao OR v.ID_ORGAO IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN PATRIMONIO_SETOR S ON S.ID_SETOR = T.ID_SETOR
LEFT JOIN PATRIMONIO_SETOR P ON P.ID_SETOR = S.ID_PARENTE
WHERE 1=1
AND P.ID_SETOR = 8
AND (V.BAIXADO = 0 OR V.BAIXADO IS NULL)
ORDER BY P.NOME, S.NOME
```

The problem is with my subquery, can I use it like this?

Comment: Do you need the nested query as you are getting `ultimo_abastecimento` and `qtd` where they are the same, so wouldn't the 2nd subquery do what you require?  Is there a need for the MAX in that query, are you just trying to get unique `qtd`'s?

Comment: After a sub-select you need to add an alias for that table (near the X  in `....group by fa.veiculo 
              )  X
        ) s`    (but there are more errors.... )

Comment: I see at least two errors in that syntax, multiple columns in a query within field list, and there is no alias for the subquery that is used within. And also there is a group by error there. Maybe instead you should give sample data and explain what you are trying to do.